# Access user data after login with Spring Boot OAuth2 Client

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, client, spring-security-oauth2

I am trying to build an OAuth2 Client using spring boot to access a custom API.

Here is my code so far:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class MyClient {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        SpringApplication.run(MyClient.class, args);
    }
}
```

```
@Configuration
@EnableOAuth2Sso
public class ApplicationSecurity extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception{
        http.antMatcher("/**")
        .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/","/callback","/login**","/error**")
        .permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated();
    }
}
```

```
@RestController
public class HomeController {
    @RequestMapping("/user")
    public String login() {
        String userInfoJson = "get data returned from API somehow";
        return userInfoJson;
    }

    @RequestMapping("/callback")
    public void callback(HttpServletResponse response) {
        response.sendRedirect("/user");
    }
}
```

I have created an application.yml file with all the properties needed and the login process works perfectly, returning the flow to /callback after a successful login.

At that point I should have received a token that I can use to fetch the user's data from the server.

How can I access this token?

Also, does spring boot have any classes to do the token validation process automatically, or do I have to create the request manually?

Thanks

Comment: you can just add the principal to the controller method to access it's content: `public void myEndpoint(Principal principal)`, if you are logged in the token has been already validated (see also https://www.baeldung.com/get-user-in-spring-security )

Comment: @Paizo I've tried it. It doesn't work. Principal is null on callback.

Answer (score 0):

from the documentation

> An OAuth2 Client can be used to fetch user details from the provider (if such features are available) and then convert them into an Authentication token for Spring Security.
>
> The Resource Server above support this via the user-info-uri property This is the basis for a Single Sign On (SSO) protocol based on OAuth2, and Spring Boot makes it easy to participate by providing an annotation @EnableOAuth2Sso.
>
> The Github client above can protect all its resources and authenticate using the Github /user/ endpoint, by adding that annotation and declaring where to find the endpoint (in addition to the security.oauth2.client.* configuration already listed above):

application.yml.

```
security:
    oauth2:
...
    resource:
        userInfoUri: https://api.github.com/user
        preferTokenInfo: false
```

So as you can read this should be done automatically if you set where the user info shall be fetched from, and then it will be populated.

When an Authentication token is populated you can fetch this from the security context in multiple different ways.

```
@RequestMapping("/callback")
public void callback(Authentication authentication) {
    final String name = authentication.getName();
    response.sendRedirect("/user");
}
```

If you wish to access the raw json, you'll probably have to make the rest call yourself. If you want to add custom values to the authentication object you have to implement your own `UserDetails` class.

Comment: The OAuth2 service I am using returns a JSON with the user's data. When I used the Authentication object, I could not figure out how to access this JSON.
`public void callback(Authentication authentication){
    String json = ??? }`

Comment: and yes spring fetches the user data, populate an authentication object. I suggest you read up on spring security about what an authentication token is, what an userdetails object is and how validation is performed in spring security.

Comment: Actually, I'm pretty sure the data hasn't been fetched at all. I even looked through the Network Monitor and as expected the data endpoint is nowhere to be found.